# Where do I start with reporting services in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have installed Visual Web Developer Express 2010, and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with advanced services.

How can I write reports to use with reporting services?

Do I need to install Visual Studio C# Express 2010 for instance?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I have found the answer here, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d3173a87-7c0d-40cc-a408-3d1a43ae4e33&displaylang=en
Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Report builder is generally a power end-user application.  When you installed SQLServer 2008 R2 there should have been an option to also install the Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS).  BIDS is essentially a very light-weight installation of Visual Studio.

Once that suite is installed you can navigate through your start menu to BIDS and create a new reporting services project.

As mentioned by Russell if you're developing against a locally running instance of SSRS, additional configuration might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a step for configuring reporting services first. Such as permissions etc.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1453

This will get your reporting services working so then you can begin to create/upload reports.